# PHP Login Question with Index file?

Tags: php

Why does my login script only work when i am at the URL: "http://localhost:80/".
Why does it not work when i am at the URL: "http://localhost/index.php".

I am using MAMP with php 5.2 on it. The Ports are set to 80 and 5506.
1. When i login from index.php it gives me a resource id 5.
2. Why does this happen and how should i fix it?

Please can you explain it in easy terms? 
Thank You

Comment: what does this hae to do with phpmyadmin?

Comment: What do you mean by resource ID 5.2?

Comment: I don't know if it was a typo on "http://localhost/index.php", it should be "http://localhost:80/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error inside your login script with the data you are returning.  PHP has a resource variable type it uses for database connections and file handles.  In your code you are apparently doing an "echo $var", and $var is a resource variable. This is why you are seeing "resource id 5".

You should probably make a new php/mysql question, that includes the source where this is occurring, if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing you file through MAMP Localhost then appending index.php. Try removing the http:// when you go through your server/Localhost it doesn't include the http://..